# Iterate last N dictionary elements in Django templates

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates

I need to iterate last N dictionary elements in Django template something like this:

```
for element in dict[-(len(dict)-3)]
    # printing
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I founded, there is no simple way to do this because dictionary is an unordered object.